# How to add/insert files such as pdf, xls etc. to mysql database using c# form application

Tags: c#, mysql

I am developing a form application using C# and using mysql as database. I simply need to add or insert any type of files (.pdf, .doc, .xls etc) into mysql table column (say attachment table , column name is files, database name say MYDB). 
Can anyone suggest the code in C# or the procedure in mysql to do the same.

I searched through the Internet but no relevant answer I found.
Any answer would be most appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to store the files themselves or just the location (path)?  If you want to store the files, you'll need to insert them into a binary field (convert them to a byte array first).

Answer (score 0):

You can insert any type of file by using this code....
uFileExpiryCapping pass 0 in this parameter.

In most of case  uFilePhysicalPath will be same as uFilePath

```
public int UploadFileToDB(string uFilePath, string uFilename, string uFileType, int uFileExpiryCapping, string uFilePhysicalPath)
        {
            int intResult = 0;
            try
            {
                string strConnectionString = string.Empty;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(uFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
                byte[] fileData = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(fileData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                DataSet ds = new DataSet("UploadedFiles");
                // Set up parameters (7 input and 1 output) 
                SqlParameter[] arParms = new SqlParameter[6];

                //@UserName Input Parameter
                arParms[0] = new SqlParameter("@UploadedFile", SqlDbType.Image);
                arParms[0].Value = fileData;
                arParms[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                //@FirstName Input Parameter
                arParms[1] = new SqlParameter("@UploadedFileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                arParms[1].Value = uFilename;
                arParms[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                //@LastName Input Parameter
                arParms[2] = new SqlParameter("@UploadedFileType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                arParms[2].Value = uFileType;
                arParms[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                //@MiddleName Input Parameter
                arParms[3] = new SqlParameter("@UploadedFileExpiryCapping", SqlDbType.Int);
                arParms[3].Value = uFileExpiryCapping;
                arParms[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                //@MobileNo Input Parameter
                arParms[4] = new SqlParameter("@UploadedFileSaveLocation", SqlDbType.NVarChar, int.MaxValue);
                arParms[4].Value = uFilePhysicalPath;
                arParms[4].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;




                //@DataInserted Output Parameter
                arParms[5] = new SqlParameter("@ErrorCode", SqlDbType.Int);
                arParms[5].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


                strConnectionString = ""; // initialise connection string


                using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
                {
                    intResult = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlConnection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Your Procedure", arParms);
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Dispose();
            }
            return intResult;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either store them as [`BINARY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179366(v=sql.105).aspx) or [`VARCHAR`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175055(v=sql.105).aspx) fields or [`FILESTREAM`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx) by submitting them to your database as `byte[]` (a `byte` array). Whether you prefer one approach over the other will depend on your personal preference and use case (ie. How many objects are stored? What are the average filesizes?)

[Recommended usage for uploading images/BLOB in this manner is explained on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f5s1we0(v=vs.110).aspx)